# How to say "thank you for ..."?

Tags: translation, mandarin, expressions

In order to say "thank you", I can say 谢谢 or 谢谢你. What if I want to be more specific and say "thank you for (something)"?

As an example, suppose I was invited for dinner at someone's place, and I want to write a card to the host on which I say "thank you for inviting me for dinner", how would I say that? Or how would I say "thank you for the gift"?

Comment: If it's a physical object, you can say "谢谢你的+[object]". Example: https://outspokenlanguage.com/morsels/zho-cn/3a3f9661a2/thank-you-for-the-fruit/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same as English just without the `for`.

谢谢 + what.

"thank you for the gift" = 谢谢 + 礼物 － maybe you would say 你送给我的礼物 or just 你的礼物

"you for inviting me for dinner" = 谢谢 + 邀请 + 晚餐 - so altogether you would say 谢谢你那天邀请我吃晚饭 (which is for what already happened - seeing as you're writing a card, so obviously you're thanking for the dinner you've already eaten and not just for the invitation for an upcoming dinner)

Answer (score 2):

1. thank you for inviting me for dinner 
   谢谢你邀请我与你共进晚餐 this saying is much more gentle than "谢谢你那天邀请我吃晚饭". Use the first sentence if you had dinner in senior restaurant and use the second sentence if you had dinner in your friend's home or it was just a common meal.
2. thank you for the gift
   谢谢你的礼物， and it could be much better if you say "谢谢你的礼物，我很喜欢"(thank you for the gift, i like it very much)

Learn more skill about [how to say Thank You in Chinese](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/daily-chinese-learning-tips/how-to-say-thank-you-in-chinese/).

Answer (score 1):

in most cases you appreciate for doing sth. or for a specific objective. That is 谢谢你 + verb phrase / 谢谢你的 + noun

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the reason and the degree of gratitude.

If someone gives you something physical or someone does something for you, you say 謝謝 in Mandarin.

If someone gives you something physical, you say 多謝 in Cantonese.

If someone does something for you, you say 唔該 in Cantonese.

If someone does you a really big favor and you want to express deep gratitude, you can say 勞駕/有勞 in Mandarin.

BTW, if you want someone to do something for you, you also say 請/麻煩 in Mandarin or 唔該 in Cantonese before the requested action, e.g. 唔該借借/請讓一讓 (meaning something like "Please" or "Excuse me").